# Porque se destruye la alineación del Label RCP Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Es una aplicación RCP, se tiene un(a) LIST de un Objeto(nombre, cantidad, imagen), esta se descarga por medio de un Bucle FOR.

Esta información se va bajando y cada atributo del objeto se muestra en el APP con un Label c/u.

Por ejemplo:

```
lblName[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, getObject().getName(), 8);
lblName[idx].setBounds(5, pos, 195, 20);

lblValue[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, getObject().getValue(), 8);
lblValue[idx].setBounds(205, pos, 73, 20);

lblStatus[idx] = ComponentProvider.getLabel(composite, "", 8);
lblStatus[idx].setBounds(280, pos, 39, 20);
lblStatus[idx].setImage(StateIconManager.getImageForState(getObject().getImg()));
```

Así se alinea estos tres atributos y se muestra en pantalla:

```
[Nombre] [Cantidad] [Imagen]
```

Esto funciona, el problema aqui es: Después de un tiempo de corrido el APP,
se desalinea asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea para que los Labels se queden siempre alineados.

Comment: Tendrías que meterlos en un Layout y a partir de ahí jugar con ellos, mira a ver por internet cual te ayudaría más en tu caso, yo pienso que igual el GridLayout estaría bien.

Comment: Cada campo en este caso 4, donde se mostraran los Labels ([Nombre][Cantidd][Imagen]), reciben un Composite, SetLayout, GridLayout y GridData. asi:
compGroup[0][0] = new Composite(group, SWT.BORDER, 3, 320, 120);  
compGroup[0][1] = new Composite(group, SWT.BORDER, 3, 320, 120);  
....



ya tienen un Layout (justamente el GridLayout) sin embargo así no se quedan estables.